# why python selenium get the empty page_source?

Tags: python, selenium

I try to simulate the buy item operation on the link below. (Need login in first)

[taobao_item_link](https://detail.tmall.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.14.33.628a41b3IQqugE&id=534808356122&ns=1&abbucket=8)

And after you click the button below.

img_link:
[image: img]

The link will jump to a [new link](https://buy.taobao.com/auction/buy_now.jhtml?x-itemid=534808356122&x-uid=671185909).

But if I print out the page_source now I will get the empty value.

Why this happen?

And of course any element location will lead to the :

**selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException**

I search on Google and I know that it's not caused by the unload of the page.

So why this happen and how to  fix it?

Here is the code I use. 
The account name and the code are in the cfg file.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import os
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  #需要引入keys包
chromedriver = "chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver

d = {}
with open("cfg.ini", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
       (key, val) = line.split()
       d[key] = val

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://login.taobao.com/member/login.jhtml')
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id('J_Quick2Static').click()
driver.find_element_by_id("TPL_username_1").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("TPL_username_1").send_keys(d['accountname'])

driver.find_element_by_id("TPL_username_1").send_keys(Keys.TAB)
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_name("TPL_password").send_keys(d['code'])

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#J_SubmitStatic').click()

print('-' * 20)
print(d['phone'])
driver.get(d['itemurl'])

element=WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(lambda driver :
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#J_LinkBuy'))

# with open('res1.html', 'a') as the_file:
   # the_file.write(driver.page_source)
element.click()

element=WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(lambda driver :
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#J_phone'))

driver.find_element_by_id('J_phone').click()

print('here is the page')
print(driver.page_source)
```

The cfg file is like this :

```
accountname xxx
code xxxx
phone xxxx
itemurl xxxx
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using? Also the image in your post isn't visible.

Comment: @KoenMeijer I already add the code thanks for reminding, and you need taobao account and pwd

Answer (score 1):

You have to switch to the new window to make it work:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('J_phone').click()

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

print('here is the page')
print(driver.page_source)
```

In this way you tell Selenium with which window it must work.

Comment: I try this code but the exception says that the index is out of range, and I print the length of the window_handles is 1. I don't know why.