# How to scrape JavaScript webpages using PhantomJS?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler, phantomjs

I am trying to Crawl this [site](https://www.paycomonline.net/v4/ats/web.php/jobs?clientkey=D25120971391831BA4315C705AA7ABF1&jpt=) and get the links of each Job posting. I am using the Selenium and PhantomJS to render the webpage, but I am not able to find the links in the rendered content. This is the script I am using

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
        String url="https://www.paycomonline.net/v4/ats/web.php/jobs?clientkey=D25120971391831BA4315C705AA7ABF1&jpt=";
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.LINUX);
        RemoteWebDriver driver = getRemoteDriver("http://localhost:9515", capabilities);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(url);
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 360)
        .until(RemoteWebDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) RemoteWebDriver)
                .executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
        byte[] content = driver.getPageSource().getBytes();
        
        String html = new String(content);
        System.out.println(html);

    }
```

I am running PhantomJS in my local machine at port 9515.Can someone help?

Comment: getPageSource() has issues and probably isn't what you actually want. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why python selenium get the empty page\_source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513509/why-python-selenium-get-the-empty-page-source)

Comment: No, I am trying to extract the Jobpostings links from the page

Comment: so then why are you using getPageSource? Why not findElements and specify the locators to the links?

Comment: I am trying to use this to crawl several sites. Render Page; get linkk from the page: render those Crawled links

Comment: driver.findElement(By.tagName("a")); will return all the anchor tags.